# Transform Java object into JSON compatible with D3's circle packing graph

Tags: java, json, recursion, gson

I have a java data structure which looks like the following

```
public class Dir {
    private Map<String, Dir> dirs = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, GitFile> files = new HashMap<>();
    private String name;
    public Dir(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This represents a directory structure where each directory can have more directories or files.
I am able to properly populate it as well using other helper methods.

Now the challenge is to convert it to a format which looks like the following

```
{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "something",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "some_other",
          "children": null,
          "size": 138
        },
        {
          "name": "some_other_other",
          "children": null,
          "size": 305
        }
      ],
      "size": 443
    }
  ]
}
```

To achieve this I have written the following methods

```
public JsonObject toJson(){
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        return buildJson(object);
    }

    private JsonObject buildJson(JsonObject object){
        System.out.println("generating json for "+this.name);
        for(Map.Entry<String,Dir> entry:dirs.entrySet()){

            Dir thisDir = entry.getValue();
            object.addProperty("name",thisDir.name);
            JsonArray element = (JsonArray) new Gson().toJsonTree( thisDir.files.values());
            element.add(thisDir.toJson());
            object.add("children",element);

        }
        System.out.println(object);
        return object;
    }
```

But this somehow only returns me the files from the last directory. Any ideas will be really helpful

This is how I am calling the method

```
def projectDir = new Dir("/")
        projectDir.addFile(new GitFile("/dev/", "talk.txt", 21, 109210))
        projectDir.addFile(new GitFile("/etc/", "talk.txt", 21, 109210))
        projectDir.addFile(new GitFile("/Users/sapanparikh", "talk.txt", 21, 109210))
        projectDir.addFile(new GitFile("/Users/sapanparikh/development", "main.java", 12, 1229))
        projectDir.addFile(new GitFile("/Users/sapanparikh/development/cat", "cat.java", 90, 309210))
        projectDir.addFile(new GitFile("/Users/savi/development/cat", "cat.java", 90, 309210))
        JsonObject jsonObject = projectDir.toJson();
```

And finally printing the JSON object will give me the following

```
{
    "name": "Users",
    "children": [{
        "name": "sapanparikh",
        "children": [{
            "path": "/Users/sapanparikh",
            "name": "talk.txt",
            "changeFrequency": 21,
            "loc": 109210
        }, {
            "name": "development",
            "children": [{
                "path": "/Users/sapanparikh/development",
                "name": "main.java",
                "changeFrequency": 12,
                "loc": 1229
            }, {
                "name": "cat",
                "children": [{
                    "path": "/Users/sapanparikh/development/cat",
                    "name": "cat.java",
                    "changeFrequency": 90,
                    "loc": 309210
                }, {}]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Here is the gist of the whole Java program
https://gist.github.com/sapanparikh18/5365ec4d5a3d82b7c2f9489af34d7840

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the files of the intermediate folders are not treated in buildJson. Rather I would use a recursive method call to do it. This works for me:

```
private JsonObject buildJson(JsonObject object){
    System.out.println("generating json for "+this.name);
    object.addProperty("name", this.name);
    JsonArray allChildren = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject aChild;
    for(Map.Entry<String,Dir> entry:dirs.entrySet()){
        aChild=new JsonObject();
        Dir thisDir = entry.getValue();            
        thisDir.buildJson(aChild);
        allChildren.add(aChild);
    }
    JsonArray thisFiles = (JsonArray) new Gson().toJsonTree( this.files.values());
    allChildren.addAll(thisFiles);
    if (allChildren.size() == 0)
        allChildren=null;
    object.add("children",allChildren);
    System.out.println(object);
    return object;
}
```